# WPF Open With Menu

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

Is there a way in a WPF application to open the "opens with" dialog that you see when right clicking a file in windows explorer and selecting "opens with"?

Comment: could you please elaborate..are you talking about context menu on specific control?

Comment: Yes. It will be a context menu. Was hoping to give the open with option so they could pick which software to use when opening a file, sometimes the default association is what you want, sometimes not.

Comment: You can use the OpenFileDialog for that and set the filter to your desired applications. Like for pdf file. C:\Adobe.exe file_path_to_open will open the file in adobe

Comment: I found the command. 

rundll32.exe shell32.dll,OpenAs_RunDLL <filename.ext>

Comment: Process.Start("rundll32.exe", string.Format("shell32.dll,OpenAs_RunDLL {0}", somefile.ext));

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is how I ended up handling this. I added some exception handling around this and it's working as expected.

```
Process.Start("rundll32.exe", string.Format("shell32.dll,OpenAs_RunDLL {0}", somefile.ext));
```

Comment: great for you...Now i understand your question :P

Answer (score -1):

I think you are talking about OpenFileDialog

```
    // Create OpenFileDialog 
     Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
     // Set filter for file extension and default file extension 
     dlg.DefaultExt = ".png";
     dlg.Filter = "All Image Files (*.png;*.bmp;*.jpg;*jpeg)|*.png;*.bmp;*.jpg;*jpeg|JPEG Files (*.jpeg)|*.jpeg|PNG Files (*.png)|*.png|JPG Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|BMP Files (*.bmp)|*.bmp";
     // Display OpenFileDialog by calling ShowDialog method 
      Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

    // Get the selected file name and display in a TextBox 
   if (result == true)
   {

   }
```

If you are talking about file association then you can use 
[http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php](http://Inno%20Setup). after installation, files will be associated with your extension and the executing file path can be accessed by commandline args.

Comment: No, I'm not talking about the OpenFileDialog. In windows Explorer, if you right click a file one of the options is "Open With" and if you click it you get a list of installed software to choose from, allowing you to choose which software you want to open the current file with. In general the default association works, but there are times where it does not. One example if I typically use notepadd++ to look at txt/log files, but if the file is to large i use glogg instead. That is just an example.

Comment: I understand your problem. But what exactly you want at application level (.NET WPF only)

Answer (score -1):

This example demonstrates how to open file with an associated program. It shows, how to open text document in notepad, how to open image in a default viewer or how to open url address in a default web browser.

Applications are launched using `Process.Start` method. The file path or url is passed as a parameter.

```
// open text file in notepad (or another default text editor)
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\textfile.txt");

// open image in default viewer
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\image.jpg");

// open url in default web browser
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.csharp-examples.net");

// open PDF file
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\document.pdf");
```

Similarly you can open Word document or any other file from your .NET application.